# I want my html input field to have two decimal places and auto update value when user is typing, Is it possible with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, numbers, decimal, user-input

**For example lets say the user needs to type 112.56,**

So when **user types 1**, input field becomes **1.00**
Next when **user types 1 again**, input field becomes **11.00**
Next when **user types 2**, input field becomes **112.00**
Next when **user types '.' (the decimal point)**, input field still is **112.00**
Then **user types 5**, input field becomes **112.50**
Last **user types 6**, and input field becomes **112.56**

I've seen this achieved in my local atm machines, I'm wondering if this is achievable via html/javascript or requires a different language

**I want it to update while the user is still typing and NOT looking for `Number.prototype.toFixed()` or `Number.prototype.toLocaleString()` kind of a solution**

Answer (score 2):

yes you can do this with JS. You can add an event listener and trigger function on every input value change. For instance:

```
const input = document.getElementById("yourInputId");

input.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
  //current input value
  const value = event.target.value;

  //position of the cursor for focused input (this only works for text password, search, tel, url, week, month, textarea input types)
  const cursorPosition = input.selectionStart;

   //now you need a series of if statements to check the current cursor position and input field value and based on that to tweak that same value and position

  //in every one of those statements you will set desired value format with: 
  input.value = ... //what you determined (e.g. input.value = value.toFixed(2))

  //and you will set a new cursor position with:
  input.setSelectionRange(startValue, endValue); // (e.g input.setSelectionRange(2, 2, "backward"); in case when user entered '.' )
```

I hope this helps. But, of course, you need to write logic (series of if statements that I mentioned) for every case you can have.